# Scrambled screen even before booting

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios, acer-aspire

I have an Acer laptop (Aspire 4740g). Recently it has the following problem.

When I turn it on, even the boot menu shows funny characters. That means is not the operating system. Running memtest, using the SystemRescueCD, and it turn off itself after 5 minutes or so. Half of the screen was not readble while it was running.

I tried removing the memory cheaps by turns, and it didn't work. I mean: I has two dimms (or whatever the are called now). One 2gb, the other 4gb. I tried putting each of them in each slot. Four combinations. Same error in all cases.

I updated the BIOS, using the crysis, and it seems to have updated normally as it went back to the default configuration.

The screen is just fine when I start windows in default mode.
I don't think is the screen because of the memtest failure.

My hypotesis are bad ram or motherboard problem, but I don't want to expend money on ram unless I'm more sure that can be the actual problem.
The memtest failure suggest a memory problem, or maybe a problem in memory controller of the motherboard problem.

The fact that the same error appear even using one of the dimms maybe think it's unlikely both end up damaged. If that's right, the diagnosis move towards a memory board problem.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: so can you read the BIOS screen ok? otherwise I would suspect the physical screen is damaged, or there is a bad connection between motherboard and screen.

Comment: The bios screen is also scrambled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to try and factory reset the bios by removing the bios jumpers from the motherboard and reseating them. But I wouldn't suggest you do it unless you know how to disassemble  and 're assemble and know at least the basics of where the components are located and how to remove them. I learned to do so by watching YouTube videos and self discovery.  Otherwise I'd suggest try a different memory stick, even if it's just a 1gig to test whether it's the ram or the ram slot. That would be your safest bet if you don't want to go as far as bios jumper removal. After that test of the issue persist, then you can tick of memory test as been ok and the issue maybe else where.

Comment: Thanks. Will do. (Don't let me vote up your question)

Comment: How'd you buddy?

Comment: Couldn't find a DIMM and didn't have time to learn and do the jumper stuff, so we'll send it to technical service. I hope is not the motherboard. Thanks for asking.

Comment: It's possibly not the motherboard, however we almost ruled out that it's your RAM sticks, so if it's the DIMMs then it means motherboard may require replacing. If it's not, then possibly bad ram or the bios like mentioned before.But is your laptop still under warranty? If so you could always get them to replace either your laptop or your motherboard without any charge. Taking it to a service guy could be costly.

Comment: It's like 5 years old. Let's see